# gpxpy not outputting extensions in to_xml()

Tags: python, gpx

I am trying to convert a custom gpx file used by an [extension of OpenCPN](http://opencpn.org/ocpn/Plugins_external_odraw) to a standard gpx file.

I want to preserve as many fields as possible including extensions.
I am able to read extensions from the gpx file using [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and able to add them to the gpx object using [gpxpy](https://github.com/tkrajina/gpxpy).

When using gpxpy.to_xml() the output is printed correctly but without the extensions.

Example:

**Source**:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
import gpxpy.gpx

f = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('odraw.gpx')
gpx = gpxpy.gpx.GPX()
gpx.creator = "a"
odpoint = f.find("{http://www.opencpn.org}path").find("{http://www.opencpn.org}ODPoint")
w1 = gpxpy.gpx.GPXWaypoint()
w1.latitude = odpoint.attrib.get('lat')
w1.longitude = odpoint.attrib.get('lon')
w1.extensions = {odpoint.find('{http://www.opencpn.org}guid')}
w1.type = 'WPT'
gpx.waypoints.append(w1)
print(gpx.to_xml())
```

**Input file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<OCPNDraw version="0.1" creator="OpenCPN" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:opencpn="http://www.opencpn.org">
 <opencpn:path>
    <opencpn:type>Boundary</opencpn:type>
    <opencpn:ODPoint lat="47.0" lon="59.0">
        <opencpn:type>Boundary Point</opencpn:type>
        <opencpn:guid>4fbfffff-806d-4317-b245-4e6e2d190000</opencpn:guid>
    </opencpn:ODPoint>
 </opencpn:path>
</OCPNDraw>
```

**Output** (Which is missing the guid extension):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0/gpx.xsd" version="1.0" creator="a">
   <wpt lat="47.0" lon="59.0">
        <type>WPT</type>
   </wpt>
</gpx>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no `extension`s in GPX version 1.0. You should serialise to xml with:

```
gpx.to_xml(version="1.1")
```

EDIT:

The problem is this line:

```
w1.extensions = {odpoint.find('{http://www.opencpn.org}guid')}
```

the `extensions` attribute must be a dictionary. You defined it as a set.

Comment: When I did that I got an exception which I do not see in version 1.0: AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: @CaptainNemo weird, can you open an issue and paste a stack trace on https://github.com/tkrajina/gpxpy/issues ... I'll see if I can figure out the problem.